# Azure B2C signup email prefill value

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am new to Azure B2C. I just practising the custom policies with their [active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main)

I am trying to set a default prefilled value in the signup. First I tried with reading from query param mentioned like this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63635675). But its not pre populates the value. I just gave an hard code value to check. But that too is not working.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
            Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"
              DefaultValue="myemail@example.com"
              AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

First of all, I don't need any signin page. I only want Signup page. So I changed In the B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase.xml file replace the 1st Orchestration Step for the User Journey Id="SignUpOrSignIn" with the following Orchestration Step and you will be directly landed to Signup page

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Its opens the Signup page first. But Its not pre filling the email value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the InputClaim to the [DisplayControl InputClaims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-controls#input-claims) collections. Eg:

```xml
<DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailAddress" />
  </InputClaims>
  ...
```

Take a look at the [Custom email verification - DisplayControls samples](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol). The `login_hint` param is used to pre-populate the aforementioned claim.